# metaSEM and casual mediation analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, mediation

This is a multi-group study and my plan is

1. Conduct casual mediation analysis (**'mediation'** package)separately for 4 groups and find a final mediator which is suitable for most groups.
2. Apply meta-analysis(**'metaSEM'** package) to check if this mediator is stable for all the groups to tell the group difference.

When I apply the **meta()** function to do the univariate meta analysis, I get the result as both **direct and indirect** effect are not significant and tau shows as NA. But I did the mediation analysis in the first step, the results show this mediator is significant as well as the predictor. (Though the estimated effect size is small but still significant.) I'm very confused by the conflict results from step1 and 2.

I would be super grateful if you could give me any suggestions about it. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, I have no idea what it going on here but (1) why are the standard errors either very large or NA, (2) do you really have only four studies from which you hope to estimate 5 parameters?

Comment: As @mdewey said, your model is probably unidentified with only 4 studies. One way is to try a fixed-effects model. As an aside, there are issues in using an indirect effect as an effect size in meta-analysis. There are some discussions in Cheung (2022).

Cheung, M. W.-L. (2022). Synthesizing indirect effects in mediation models with meta-analytic methods. Alcohol and Alcoholism, 57(1), 5–15. https://doi.org/10.1093/alcalc/agab044